# Which questions related to cognitive science are on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, off-topic

Artificial intelligence is very related to [cognitive science](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/cognitive-science/), but which questions related to cognitive science should be on- or off-topic here? Which questions are more appropriate for our site and which ones are more appropriate for e.g. for https://psychology.stackexchange.com/?

I am looking for answers from people that are studying or have studied cognitive science and that can provide some insights.